# Ubuntu 18.04 Hyper-V stuck at grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub, hyper-v

I have small knowledge about working linux/ubuntu server. I had a problem with my current server provider. And for 1 reason, i pick up my latest server backup, which he gave me as .vhdx file (145GB).

While searching in internet, i found that Windows has a Hyper-V program and I can install this file to there.

I installed .vhdx file in Hyper-V Manager and configured as it in screenshots.

https://prnt.sc/wer7bt

https://prnt.sc/wer8wk

https://prnt.sc/wer94i

https://prnt.sc/wer9al

https://prnt.sc/wer9o3

https://prnt.sc/wer9va

When I try to start, it goes directly to grub>

https://prnt.sc/werbl4

I have these files:

https://prnt.sc/wercof

I tried some solutions which i found in internet, but nothing worked.

This was an Ubuntu Server 18.04 installed on VM.

I just want to grab my files inside of this thing, I dont need to create ubuntu server. Waiting for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BTW am not so technical,

Linux is not MS-Windows...

Ubuntu's grub/grub2  loader may not be showing all yor bootable partitions.

Read this ubuntu explanation

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

other comments

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Self discovered this with an Ubuntu default installation did not enable multi-boot(s), with only the installed ubuntu available.

With grub showing only needed provide address to start other bootable partitions.

Entering correct boot address for other bootable partitions, can have them start.

When at grub/grub2 command-line prompt and know your bootable partition addresss [eg sda2]

EXAMPLE:   set root=(hd0,sda2)

then ENTER your boot partition address, for self this proceeded to boot.

IF access your linux OS partion,  best re-build your  grub addresses.

Example: opensuse

[mount /dev/sdb8 etc wipes contents of sdb7?? What's up wit dat?](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/539638-mount-dev-sdb8-etc-wipes-contents-of-sdb7-What-s-up-wit-dat?p=2931958#post2931958)

IF access your linux OS and run the into sort partion.

With linux OS running update your grub, it find other OS's.

GPT is the newer standard replacing MBR.

GPT drives tend to include a “protective MBR.”

This type of MBR says that the GPT drive has a single partition that extends across the entire drive.

Trying to manage GPT disks with old tools may only read MBRs, may see single partition as extending across entire drive.

The protective MBR ensures old tools do not mistake GPT drives thus overwrite GPT data with a new MBR.

In other words, the protective MBR protects the GPT data from being overwritten.

When you make a change to a grub file make sure to
run the

[self with opensuse]  "sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg"

So your bootable partitions are recognised and usable.